# WPF UI element naming conventions

Tags: wpf, coding-style

Although [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) is considered bad practice nowadays, it is still quite common to encode the type in the name of *user interface elements*, either by using a prefix (`lblTitle`, `txtFirstName`, ...) or a suffix (`TitleLabel`, `FirstNameTextBox`, ...).

In my company, we also do this, since it makes code written by co-workers (or by yourself a long time ago) easier to read (in my experience). The argument usually raised against doing this -- you have to change the name of the variable if the type changes -- is not very strong, since changing the type of a UI element usually requires rewriting all parts of the code were it is referenced anyway.

So, I'm thinking about keeping this practice when starting with WPF development (hmmm... should we use the `txt` prefix for TextBlocks or TextBoxes?). Is there any big disadvantage that I have missed? This is your chance to say "Don't do this, because ...".

EDIT: I know that with databinding the need to name UI elements decreases. Nevertheless, it's necessary sometimes, e.g. when developing custom controls...

Comment: Never actually needed to name a TextBlock, so that `txt` issue may be a moot point. In Fact, you only ever need to name anything if you need to access it from code or so. Since most of WPF UI is driven by databinding and declared in XAML this greatly reduces the need of having every control named.

Comment: You'll also need to name them if other UIElements bind to them using ElementName binding.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Personally, I find that WPF changes the rules when it comes to this.  Often, you can get away with little or no code behind, so having the prefixes to distinguish names makes things more confusing instead of less confusing.

In Windows Forms, every control was referenced by name in code.  With a large UI, the semi-hungarian notation was useful - it was easier to distinguish what you were working with.

In WPF, though, it's a rare control that needs a name.  When you do have to access a control via code, it's often best to use attached properties or behaviors to do so, in which case you're never dealing with more than a single control.  If you're working in the UserControl or Window code-behind, I'd just use "Title" and "Name" instead of "txtTitle", especially since now you'll probably only be dealing with a few, limited controls, instead of all of them.

Even custom controls shouldn't need names, in most cases.  You'll want templated names following convention (ie: PART_Name), but not actual x:Name elements for your UIs...

Comment: is `PART_Name` prefix convention still used?

Comment: If you check the styles and templates generated automatically by Visual Studio you see that they name everything without a prefix and suffix and lowercase only. For example, in Expander default style:
<Ellipse x:Name="circle"/>
<Image x:Name="arrow"/>

Answer (score 13):

In my experience -  In WPF when you change the type of a control, you normally do not have to rewrite any code unless you did something wrong.   In fact, most of the time you do not reference the controls in code.   Yes, you end up doing it, but the majority of references to a UI element in WPF is by other elements in the same XAML.

And personally, I find "lblTitle, lblCompany, txtFirstName" harder to read than "Title".  I don't have .intWidth and .intHeight (goodbye lpzstrName!).  Why have .lblFirstName?   I can understand TitleField or TitleInput or whatever a lot more as it's descriptive of the what, not the how.

For me, wishing to have that type of separation normally means my UI code is trying to do too much - of course it's dealing with a UI element, it's in the window code!  If I'm not dealing with code around a UI element, why in the world would I be coding it here?

Answer (score 8):

I like using a convention (just a good idea in general), but for UI stuff I like it to have the type of the control at the front, followed by the descriptive name -- LabelSummary, TextSummary, CheckboxIsValid, etc.

It sounds minor, but the main reason for putting the type first is that they'll appear together in the Intellisense list -- all the labels together, checkboxes, and so on.

Comment: Agreed with all you said, I do the same thing for the same reasons.

Comment: If you find yourself using Intellisense to type control names into code on a regular basis, it likely means you're using WPF as if it was "bad old WinForms" and not taking full advantage of WPF's advanced features (data binding, templates, etc).

Comment: I don't disagree that WPF has a different usage model from "bad old Winforms", but I only need to look for a control name once to appreciate a convention that makes them easy to find.

Comment: This can be a pain sometimes, too -  I want to find the Title, so I try TextTi... oops.  Is it a combo? ComboTitl... er, no.  Oh, we only allow two - perhaps a radio button?  RadioTitle!  aha!

Answer (score 8):

Even from a Winforms perspective I dislike semi-hungarian.

The biggest disadvantage in my opinion, and I've written a LOT of ui code is that hungarian makes bugs harder to spot.  The compiler will generally pick it up if you try to change the checked property on a textbox, but it won't pick up something like:

```
lblSomeThing.Visible = someControlsVisible;
txtWhatThing.Visible = someControlsVisible;
pbSomeThing.Visible = someControlsVisible;
```

I find it MUCH easier to debug:

```
someThingLabel.Visible = someControlsVisible;
whatThingTextBox.Visible = someControlsVisible;
someThingPictureBox.Visible = someControlsVisible;
```

I also think it's far better to group an addCommentsButton with an addCommentsTextBox than to group a btnAddComments with a btnCloseWindow.  When are you ever going to use the last two together?

As far as finding the control I want, I agree with Philip Rieck.  I often want to deal with all the controls that relate to a particular logical concept (like title, or add comments).  I pretty much never want to find just any or all text boxes that happens to be on this control.

It's possibly irrelevant in WPF, but I think hungarian should be avoided at all times.

Answer (score 5):

Agree with the other answers that it's mainly personal preference, and most important is just to be consistent.

On the need for naming at all, given the prevalence of data binding... one thing you might want to consider is if your UI is ever subjected to automated testing. Something like [QTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_QuickTest_Professional) finds the visual elements in an application by Name, and so an automation engineer writing test scripts will greatly appreciate when things like tabs, buttons etc. (any interactive control) are all well named.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF you practically never need (or even want) to name your controls.  So if you're using WPF best practices it won't matter what you *would* name your controls *if* you had a reason to name them.

On those rare occasions where you actually do want to give a control a name (for example for an ElementName= or TargetName= reference), I prefer to pick a name describing based on the purpose for the name, for example:

```
<Border x:Name="hilightArea" ...>
   ...

<DataTrigger>
   ...
   <Setter TargetName="hilightArea" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefix any user-interface name with two underscores, as in `__` so it is sorted before other properties when debugging. When I need to use IntelliSense to find a control, I just type __ and a list of controls displays. This continues the naming convention of prefixing a single underscore to module level variables, as in `int _id;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the official Microsoft website for Visual Basic 6 control naming conventions, and perhaps combine it with the recommended C# naming conventions. It's very specific, is widely used by developers in C# as well for control names, and can still be used in a WPF or Windows Forms context.

Visual Basic 6 control naming conventions: [Object Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263493%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

C# recommended naming conventions in general: [General Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229045%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)