# Is there a standard naming convention for WPF UI controls?

Tags: .net, wpf, controls, naming-conventions

it exist some standard for notation of UI controls in WPF. Something like hungarian notation.

For example

```
<TextBox Name=tbNameOfTextBox/>
<Image   Name=imgOfMe/>
<RichTextBox Name="rtbDocument"/>
```

What kind of notation do you use?

And my second question is about sequence, organization properties in element.

Fot example I have this:

```
<ListBox Name="friendsListBox" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
         SelectedItem="Key"
         Style="{DynamicResource friendsListStyle}"
         PreviewMouseRightButtonUp="ListBox_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp"
         PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="ListBox_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" 
         Grid.Row="2" 
         Margin="4,4,4,4"
         MouseRightButtonDown="FriendsListBoxMouseRightButtonDown">
```

or

```
    <TextBox Name="TbStatus"
             Text="{Binding Path=Message, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             Style="{StaticResource CurveTextBox}"
             Grid.Column="1" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             Margin="3,3,3,3" LostFocus="TbStatus_LostFocus" />
```

In listbox I have properties such as Name, ItemSource,SelectedItem, and som Events.
What is appropriate to their organization. The first should be the name of the UI control, then the events and finally style properties?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743467/wpf-ui-element-naming-conventions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Control naming

Post suggested by Cody Gray should be sufficient [WPF UI element naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743467/wpf-ui-element-naming-conventions)

2) Event naming

I prefer to use the same convention as Visual Studio "<ControlName>_<EventName>". When you type event name and hit TAB it generates method for you. Don't see any reason to spend time on renaming it, other than using it on multiple controls - in such case you'd want to provide some generic descriptive name for the handler.

3) Attributes order

Mine is: first name (if exists), events last. All other attributes should be grouped by their impact - appearance related (background, foreground, opacity, etc.), layout related (height, width, aligments), etc. 
Not to have "width" in top of your attributes list and "height" somewere in the bottom.

Comment: Good answer.  I would only add that the most important thing is to remain consistent in your naming convention and coding style.  It makes maintenance so much easier, especially if it is somebody else looking at your code.  Of course, this applies to the code-behind as well.

Comment: @Wonko the Sane: I agree, that's the most important thing

Comment: If event handlers are named like that, and you name an event handler after a field that starts with lowercase, doesn't that violate the rule about capitalizing methods?

Answer (score 2):

I think mostly this is a matter of personal preferences so many people may disagree with me here. Just answering how I do this.

**For your first question**
We had a long ongoing discussion about this at my former company and finally we decided to go with camel casing ending with the control type and no abbreviations. So in your case

```
<TextBox Name="nameOfTextBox"/> 
<Image Name="meImage"/> 
<RichTextBox Name="documentRichTextBox"/>
```

This is for sure no standard but I use it all the time

**For your second question**
I think a good way is to place the Name property first, then attached properties (like Grid.Row, Grid.Column etc) and then the Style. After that group by categories, like layout, visibilty etc. The events should come last. Example

```
<ListBox Name="friendsListBox"
         Grid.Row="2"
         Style="{DynamicResource friendsListStyle}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding}"
         SelectedItem="Key"
         Margin="4,4,4,4"
         PreviewMouseRightButtonUp="friendsListBox_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp"
         PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="friendsListBox_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown"
         MouseRightButtonDown="friendsListBox_MouseRightButtonDown">

<TextBox Name="statusTextBox"
         Grid.Column="1"
         Style="{StaticResource CurveTextBox}"
         Text="{Binding Path=Message,
                        Mode=TwoWay,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         TextWrapping="Wrap"
         Margin="3,3,3,3"
         LostFocus="statusTextBox_LostFocus" />
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `c_` prefix?  What problem is it solving?

Comment: I agree with part 2, but isn't the use of c_ and the control type redundant?  And won't everything in the XAML be named c_something, which is also redundant?  It's also a bit confusing, because c_ could also mean, to somebody new, "constant."

Comment: Like I said in the answer, it's a matter of personal preferences. Anyway, I seemed to be outnumbered here so I removed that part from the answer :)