# .Net - Better way of naming control - Hungarian Notation or Full Notation such as lbl or Label

Tags: .net

In the old days, we name controls as lblFirstName, txtFirstName.

I'm seeing more and more full names like FirstNameLabel, FirstNameTextBox. Obviously, it doesn't make any different.

My question is whether Microsoft officially recommended using full name like FirstNameLabel.

If this question has been asked, please forgive me.

Comment: This might help you [WPF UI element naming conventions][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743467/wpf-ui-element-naming-conventions

Comment: This is 'systems hungarian', the bad kind.  It went really of control, this KB article is hilarious: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173738

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a "type" prefix is of the old [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) days. It's generally not recommended for use when developing new applications.

The only time I would recommend it is when you're working with a legacy product that uses the convention throughout the application just for the sake of consistency.

Edit:

From [MSDN Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx):

**Do not use Hungarian notation.**

Hungarian notation is the practice of including a prefix in identifiers to encode some metadata about the parameter, such as the data type of the identifier.

Comment: I agree. However, I cannot find any official recommendations by Microsoft.

Comment: Can you say where you heard it's not recommended anymore and/or why?

Comment: @Ash The most logical reason I've ever heard is from Code Complete, by Steve McConnell, which basically states that if you're writing such cryptic code that you need type identifiers in the variable names, you're doing it wrong. (Obviously paraphrasing here, but I can find the exact text if you wish...)

Comment: Thats fine. The msdn link was all I needed :)

Comment: I find it rather amuzing that there seems to be a general consensus against Hungarian notation because you only need the type if the code is cryptic while at the same moment many have strang fealings about 'var' because they "need" to know the type...

Comment: @Rune A bit off topic, but I personally don't like using var for implicit types (unless I'm just throwing out a prototype or something, maybe). There is a reason for the var keyword, and that's for compile time type inference on anonymous types, which is necessary. And var has a very limited scope, compared to "g_nSumNum".

Answer (score 6):

For **UI Only** objects such as a textbox or label; the convention of notating what sort of windows control it is is valid, and since it's been a tradition in .NET, I see no reason to change it.  If your company has a different standard, use that standard; but for UI controls, the convention I've seen has always been to use the three letter prefix (I hesitate to call it hungarian notation, but that's the closest thing it resembles).

Comment: Note that in Winforms at least, sometimes it's still really important to know what the type of the control is, e.g., in a `TextBox` you use `Text` to set the string displayed. `NumericUpDown` also has a `Text` property [but it doesn't do anything](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs40s7ds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and you use `Value` instead. It might not matter where you put the type of the control (the front or the end) but it's not really possible to just completely ignore the type; if there's no type implied at all in the name, you'll end up hovering over all the time in the code.

Answer (score 3):

I don't agree not to use **Hungarian notation**, I think there are cases where it helps a lot, mainly in **UI programming** where you name your **controls** with prefixes like `txt_` `lbl_` and such, so you can find them very fast with intellisense when you need them. If this is cryptic opposed to memorising and being 100% fully concentrated on your variables having all their names in your head ...

What I find really redundant is having _ sign before private variables in classes, but this is different topic.

Answer (score 3):

Read Joel's explanation on the origin of Hungarian Notation:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

The gist is that it's not that useful in type-safe languages.

Comment: Interesting article. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't know already... he's one of the guys that started StackOverflow. Check out more of his articles or books.

Answer (score 2):

Intellisense makes Hungarian notation less useful but I'm having trouble coming to terms with not using Hungarian notation. If I want to hide a textbox and the associated label on the fly I find  lblTown.visible=false and txtTown.visible=false intuitive. How do you do this without naming controls? TownLabel and TownTextBox seem to add more characters to type and no more information.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [Microsoft link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110264) I found for their recommended naming conventions (Visual Basic).