# C# Visual Studio 2017 cannot implicitly convert type string to windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, type-conversion

Just started in c# and want to create simple UWP application, i have TextBlock and Button, i want when press Button TextBlock text changes but always get error:

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock Text = "HELLO";
    }
```

> CS0029  C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock'

I am confused, why Text field don't understand string.
Thanks for helping.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="105,306,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="146" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="56,141,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="107" Width="241" SelectionChanged="TextBlock_SelectionChanged" FontSize="36"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

xaml:

```
<Grid>
<Button Name="btn" Click="Button_Click" Content="Button"/>
<TextBlock Name="tb"/>
</Grid>
```

xaml.cs:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tb.Text = "HELLO";
}
```

or remove Click event and put this on constructor

```
btn.Click += (se, arg) => tb.Text = "HELLO";
```

by the way, TextBlock doesn't have SelectionChanged event

Answer (score 0):

To explain what Christopher made above *(his code is correct)*:

He added an identifier in the XAML code to the TextBlock object.

```
Name="tb"
```

And then in the C# code he used the identifier to refer to the TextBlock object.

Since you said you're new to C#, let me give you a golden advice. Always give variabels and objects *(such as buttons, textboxes etc.)* names *(identifiers)* in relation to their assignment. That way it's much easier for you to use them later in the code.

A little tip to shorten a few commonly used named objects:

- Button = btn
- Textbox = tbx
- Label = lbl

Comment: These are some bad recommendations.

Comment: You either didn't understand the obvious point that i.e. a button that applies something can be named btnApply for instance and not just named "btn", or I'd love to hear an explanation of your statement.

Comment: Here is some advice to you. First, use `x:Name` to name your controls, **do not** `Name`. Second, don't use abbreviations as part of the name. They are confusing. How are you gonna name `AppBarButton`, `RadioButton`, `ToggleButton`, `RepeatButton`, etc.? Say if you have a `Button` that does SUBMIT, just called it "Submit".

Comment: @JustinXL I use similar names - "Bt" for `Button` and then `ABB` for `AppBarButton`, `RB` for `RadioButton` and so on so it's possible.

Comment: @MarianDolinský have a look at all MSFT official docs, you rarely see people do this. What if you extend the AppBarButton to ExtendedAppBarButton? Then EABB? You might know what it is but it will be confusing for other devs just by looking at it. Have a read on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743467/wpf-ui-element-naming-conventions).

Comment: I'm not saying it's common habit, I'm just saying it's possible, however, I must admit, with longer types it's kinda hard to choose the right prefix. Thinking about it, it's just an old habit my teacher taught me in my first year on high school and I should really stop it. Thanks for the link. :)

Comment: @MarianDolinský Oh yeah it's definitely possible. :) I tend to use *verb* to describe buttons but if you want to add "Button" in the end like `SubmitButton` is perfectly fine. I believe built-in controls are doing this.